# Grep with multiple strings and wildcard

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I'm trying to get matches from a log file with multiple strings and a wildcard. This is how the log looks like

**test.log**

```
abc|07Jan2016:sessionId=F4DF
<<random log lines>>
def|08Jan2016:sessionId=5415
<<random log lines>>
abc|08Jan2016:sessionId=F4DF
<<random log lines>>
xyz|09Jan2016:sessionId=F3D2
<<random log lines>>
ijk|06Jan2016:sessionId=CF38
```

The result I'm expecting

```
abc|07Jan2016:sessionId=F4DF
ijk|06Jan2016:sessionId=CF38
```

As you can see, I just want to get the log lines that have sessionIds from lines that have the string matches 'abc' and 'ijk'

The grep command that I tried

```
grep -m 1 'abc.*sessionId\|ijk.*sessionId' test.log
```

The result I'm getting

```
ijk|06Jan2016:sessionId=CF38
```

The grep is not looking for matches with the string 'abc', but it is looking for the 'ijk' match with the wildcard '.*sessionId' Can somebody please let me know what I'm missing here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` may solve the problem:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\\|"; pat["abc"]; pat["ijk"]}
$1 in pat && /:sessionId=/ {print; delete pat[$1]}' file.log

abc|07Jan2016:sessionId=F4DF
ijk|06Jan2016:sessionId=CF38
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/deq6NX)

Comment: This did not give me any results back. Why do we have delete in this command?

Comment: I have added a code demo for the sample data you've provided. `delete` command deletes a matched entry from array `pat` so that only first matching record is printed as desired in output shown.

Comment: Thanks for attaching your demo ! I'm trying to work based off your command.. :)

Comment: I know why this command is not working for me. This command does not work if there's anything before 'abc' in the log.. for eg: if this is the first line in the log

<<   hello|abc|07Jan2016:sessionId=F4DF >>

the command will not match on that first line..

I tried removing the BEGIN part of the command, but didn't work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: If `abc` (or search string) can be first field and it can be second field as well? In that case use: `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\\|"; pat["abc"]; pat["ijk"]} /:sessionId=/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i in pat) {print; delete pat[$i]}}' file.log`

Comment: @Sandeep: Did my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. This will exit from program once one of each string's very 1st occurrence is printed, so this will not read whole Input_file.

```
awk -F'|' '
($1=="abc" || $1=="xyz") && ++arr[$1]==1{
   count++
   print
}
count==2{ exit }
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -F'|' '                                ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as | here.
($1=="abc" || $1=="xyz") && ++arr[$1]==1{  ##Checking condition if 1st field is abc OR xyz AND their respective index in array arr is ONLY 1.
   count++                                 ##Increase count with 1 here.
   print                                   ##Printing current line here.
}
count==2{ exit }                           ##Checking condition if count is 2 then exit from program.
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion with `grep`:

```
grep -E "^(abc|ijk)\|" file.log
```

Suggesting with `awk`:

```
 awk '/^(abc|ijk)\|/1' file.log
```